# Which Windows 10 login protects secure data?

Tags: encryption, windows-10, windows-dpapi

Windows can protect sensitive data using `CryptProtectData`, which according to the Windows docs, encrypts data for a given program using the user's login password.

But Windows 10 has several forms of login: Windows Hello Face, Windows Hello Fingerprint, Windows Hello PIN, Security Key, Password and Picture Password.

Which of these does Windows 10 uses for encrypting it's secrets?